# KryptonForm not showing in designer - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, krypton-toolkit, krypton

I've added the toolkit.dll as a reference, inherited **KryptonForm** instead of **Form**, successfully built the application, everything is working fine, but designer mode fail to display the form. I am getting this error:

**Could not find type 'ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: I renamed the dll thinking that will not affect in any way the application, and it didn't ! 
But somehow affects the designer: when I renamed the dll back to **ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll** Visual Studio's designer worked aswell. I am curious why behaves this way